# How to denote a range of elements in a row array?

Tags: notation, vectors, time-series, convention, index-notation

Let's say I have a row vector $\vec{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times T}$. You can consider it as the $i$-th time-series from a set of time-series.
I want to index a subsequence from $\vec{x}_i$ from $t1$ till $t2$, but I do not know how to denote it properly without causing confusion.

Can I simply denote it as $\vec{x}_i(t1:t2)$ or $\vec{x}_i |_{t1}^{t2}$?

Comment: There is no "standard notation" for that so either of those is fine as long as you explain it for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid vector arrows in print, when you are not in a geometric setting.

In elementary analysis we denote a sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ by $\bigl(a_k\bigr)_{k\geq1}$. Similarly, when $I$ is an arbitrary index set used to parametrize a family of sets $A_\iota\,$, we denote this family by $\bigl(A_\iota\bigr)_{\iota\in I}$. Note that we are talking here about arrays, not about sets of objects. When $a_1=2$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=2$ then
$$\bigl\{a_i\bigm|1\leq i\leq 3\bigr\}=\{1,2\},\qquad \bigl(a_i\bigm|1\leq i\leq 3\bigr)=(2,1,2)\ .$$
For your time series I then propose  notations like
$$\bigl(x_i\bigr)_{t_1\leq i\leq t_2}\ ,\qquad\bigl(x_i\bigr)_{i\in[t_1..t_2]}\ ,\qquad\bigl(x_i\bigm|t_1\leq i\leq t_2\bigr)\ .$$

Comment: The reason I used a vector arrow was that each sequence is taken from the corresponding row of the matrix $\mathbf{X} \in  \mathbb{R}^{d \times T}$. Also, I need to perform a dot-product between each sequence and a fixed vector $\vec{f} \in \mathbb{R}^T$ later on. Do I still have to use the above notation?